# Pivotting a table in Pervasive SQL 11

Tags: sql, pervasive

I looked at similar topics and tried some self joins but couldn't understand how to apply.

Have a table like this in Pervasive SQL 11:

```
kit|part

1 | 21

1 | 22

1 | 23

1 | 24

2 | 30

2 | 31   
....
```

Would like to return this in one row

```
1 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24

2 | 30 | 31
```

The number of related parts will vary from 1 to 30+, should only return 1 row per kit

What is the best way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

No need for a self join, just a GROUP BY with (assuming MySQL) [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT kit, GROUP_CONCAT(part)
FROM table
GROUP BY kit
```

You can choose the ordering, or add a separator:

```
SELECT kit, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT part ORDER BY part ASC SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM table
GROUP BY kit
```

However, if you want the results in seperate columns, you cannot write a dynamic self-join in MySQL that automatically joins sufficient times to have all tables, and MySQL does not support pivots. Other (R)DBMS might though.

Comment: It is okay not to have in separate columns, I liked your suggestion. However, I tried this in pervasive with my table name but gave me an expression error

Comment: Oh Pervasive? Did you add that, or did I bluntly read over it? I was assuming MySQL. Edited your question title to draw more attention from the right people :]